# typescript cant find modules to bcrypt if .ts file deeper on folder

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, bcrypt

The simple working code on project root folder (named here as systemname):

```
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt'; 

let myvalue = "JFDSNJDSNFJSDNFSJASASNDCAUDHANDKLAMDXIALWDMQAW";

bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(myvalue, salt, function(err, hash) {
        console.log(myvalue);
        console.log(hash);
        console.log(bcrypt.compareSync(myvalue,hash));
    });
});

let salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
let hash = bcrypt.hashSync(myvalue,salt);
console.log(myvalue);
console.log(hash);
console.log(bcrypt.compareSync(myvalue,hash));
```

The following code is almost the same as above but breaks only for the class stuff and by being deep inside folder structure like `systemname/T/cryptUtil.ts`  . The code is the following:

```
import * as bcrypt from "bcrypt";

export class cryptUtil {
  //-------------------------------------------------
  private _rounds: number = 10;  //0xf49f6cd693d04c7ebe6928429a24f2ce;
  public get rounds(): number {
    return this._rounds;
  }
  public set rounds(rounds: number) {
    this._rounds = rounds;
  }
  //-------------------------------------------------
  public getSalt(): string {
    return bcrypt.genSaltSync(this.rounds);
  }
  //-------------------------------------------------
  public getSaltAsynchronous(
    callback: ((err: Error, salt: string) => void)
  ): void {
    bcrypt.genSalt(this.rounds, callback);
  }
  //-------------------------------------------------
  public BCryptHashGet(passw: string): string {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(passw, this.getSalt());
  }
  //-------------------------------------------------
  public BCryptHashGetAsynchronous(
    passw: string,
    callback: ((err: Error, hash: string) => void)
  ): void {
    this.getSaltAsynchronous((err: Error, salt: string) => {
      bcrypt.hash(passw, salt, callback);
    });
  }
  //-------------------------------------------------
  public BCryptHashCompare(passw: string, hash: string): boolean {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(passw, hash);
  }
  //-------------------------------------------------
  public BCryptHashCompareAsynchronous(
    passw: string,
    hash: string,
    callback: ((err: Error, isMatch: boolean) => void)
  ): void {
    bcrypt.compare(passw, hash, callback);
  }
  //-------------------------------------------------
}
```

Another way to not receive warnings or errors is move the class to project root folder (named here as systemname) and create a file also on the root folder to test as follow:

*The file with class moved to root folder:*

```
import * as bcrypt from "bcrypt";

export class lxCryptUtil {
  //-------------------------------------------------
  lxGetSalt(rounds: number): string {
    return bcrypt.genSaltSync(rounds);
  }
  //-------------------------------------------------
  lxGetSaltAsynchronous(
    rounds: number,
    callback: ((err: Error, salt: string) => void)
  ): void {
    bcrypt.genSalt(rounds, callback);
  }
  //-------------------------------------------------
  lxBCryptHashGet(rounds: number, passw: string): string {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(passw, this.lxGetSalt(rounds));
  }
  //-------------------------------------------------
  lxBCryptHashGetAsynchronous(
    rounds: number,
    passw: string,
    callback: ((err: Error, hash: string) => void)
  ): void {
      this.lxGetSaltAsynchronous(rounds, (err: Error, salt: string) => {
      bcrypt.hash(passw, salt, callback);
    });
  }
  //-------------------------------------------------
  lxBCryptHashCompare(passw: string, hash: string): boolean {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(passw, hash);
  }
  //-------------------------------------------------
  lxBCryptHashCompareAsynchronous(
    passw: string,
    hash: string,
    callback: ((err: Error, isMatch: boolean) => void)
  ): void {
    bcrypt.compare(passw, hash, callback);
  }
  //-------------------------------------------------
}
```

*The file creatad to test the class moved to root folder:*

```
import { lxCryptUtil } from './lxCryptUtil';

export class dummy{
    processPwd(): void {
        let hash: string = "";
        let passwd: string = "FJIEJWIOEFNWONMWLEW";
        let lx = new lxCryptUtil();
        hash = lx.lxBCryptHashGet(10,passwd);
        console.log(passwd);
        console.log(hash);
        console.log(lx.lxBCryptHashCompare(passwd, hash));
    }
}

let d = new dummy();
d.processPwd();
```

If coding the most basic possible inside a `.ts` file in project root folder there is no error with `@types/bcrypt` but if put `.ts` a bit deeper and organize inside a class then i receive errors.

When doing:

```
npm run build | grep "Can't resolve"
```

remained only the following errors:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'npm' in '/systemname/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../package' in '/home/myuser/node_modules/node-gyp/lib'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' in '/systemname/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' in '/systemname/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' in '/systemname/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! systemname@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the systemname@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/myuser/.npm/_logs/2018-01-18T01_01_01_012Z-debug.log
```

Before finding ***[this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39692275/9217154)*** solution there was many other errors.

But cant keep each class in right folder to include where i want.
There is detail and current status [here](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/573).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered by @agathver here : [https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/573#issuecomment-360484895)

> NodeJS native modules contains DLLs and glue code and the module initialization code loads them into the NodeJS process. For this we need the full path to the native module. We use a library called bindings to find the correct path to the native DLL.
>
> Webpack while bundling changes those expectations (namely, the initialization code and package.json are located in the directory)

bcrypt cant be bundled